# How to populate <ul> with random object elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a random name generator app, and while I've done the work on how to get a random combination of "first" and "last" names, the problem I'm facing is that every list item shows the exact same name, though the name itself *is* random. See the code below:

```
let nameList = document.getElementById("name-list"); // <ul> in HTML doc
let names = document.getElementsByClassName("name"); // <li> in HTML doc, 10 in total

function Generate() { // onclick function

     nameList.style.display = 'block';

     randomFirstM = nameObj["male"]["first"][Math.floor(Math.random() * 
Object.keys(nameObj["male"]["first"]).length)] //nameObj is from a different JS file which contains sub-Objects for male/female and first/last names

     randomLastM = nameObj["male"]["last"][Math.floor(Math.random() * 
Object.keys(nameObj["male"]["last"]).length )]
     for(let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
         names[i].innerHTML = randomFirstM + " " + randomLastM;
     }

 }
```

So it would show something like:

- John Stevenson
- John Stevenson
- John Stevenson
- John Stevenson
- John Stevenson

Instead of:

- John Stevenson
- Richard Johnson
- George Henry
- Michael Taylor
- Aaron Stevens

Any comments and advice are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add sample data.

Comment: Actually you are using the same value of FirstName and lastname. Can you show your nameObj how does it look like

Answer (score 2):

You need to generate a random first and last name *on every iteration* of the loop - at the moment, you're only ever choosing a random name at the very beginning, and then using that same name every time. Maybe make a function that takes in an array and returns a function that chooses a random element from the array for DRY code.

Also note that dot notation is preferable to bracket notation when dot notation is possible, and that unless you're deliberately inserting HTML markup, better to assign to `.textContent` than to `.innerHTML` (it's safer, quicker, and more reliable):

```
const makeRandom = arr => {
  const { length } = arr;
  return () => arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * length)];
};
const randomFirstM = makeRandom(nameObj.male.first);
const randomLastM = makeRandom(nameObj.male.last);
for(let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  names[i].textContent = randomFirstM() + " " + randomLastM();
}
```